# CMIS workbench not connecting to inmemory/Alfresco repository

Tags: alfresco, cmis, cmis-workbench

I have setup inmemory repository on Tomcat7 and trying to access it using cmis workbench. As per instructions, I am using

```
http://localhost:8080/inmemory/atom
```

as URL for binding & leaving all other things default but I am getting "Service Unavailable" error as below with warning in log4j.log file under tomcat/bin.

> WARN  [localhost-startStop-1]
>   org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.inmemory.server.InMemoryServiceFactoryImpl:
>   Resource file with type definitions types.xml could not be found, no
>   types will be created.

[image: CMIS Workbench Error]

Next I tried to connect to my local Alfresco 4.2 repo using same workbench with atom URL as

```
 http://localhost:8080/alfresco/cmisatom
```

with admin credentials but again I am getting same error as below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

go to http://www.alfresco.com/cmis

There is a link to the workbench: http://cmis.alfresco.com/opencmis/workbench.jnlp

Use the alfresco cmisatom url: http://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisatom

Login as admin with password admin.
This one works and you can even try your local repo.

Comment: Thanks Tahir, its working now using http://cmis.alfresco.com/opencmis/workbench.jnlp. Can you tell what is the issue with regular workbenches?

Comment: Probably you've got a faulty workbench installed. Pull another one from the apache site: http://chemistry.apache.org/java/how-to/how-to-build.html

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded latest version 0.10.0 from http://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html but it was not working also. So can i assume that i need to build it using maven to get it working?

Comment: Yep you need maven to build it

Answer (score 1):

Open these URLs in a web browser. If you see a "Service Unavailable" error then it's not a CMIS Workbench problem.
You can also try a nightly build of the CMIS Workbench [1], which provides more detailed error messages.

[1] https://builds.apache.org/job/Chemistry%20-%20OpenCMIS%20-%20Workbench/ws/chemistry-opencmis-workbench/target/